# Валидация всех полей формы

Tags: javascript

Как сделать чтобы валидация происходиладля  всех полей сразу а не по одному

```js
if (firstname.length < 3) firstname_eror = "Имя не меньше 3 символов";
               else if (lastname.length < 3) lastname_eror = "Имя не меньше 3 символов";
               else if (email_address.split ('@').length - 1 == 0 || email_address.split ('.').length - 1 == 0) fail = "Вы ввели некорректный адрес эл. почты";
                if (firstname_eror != "") {
                  $('#firstname_eror').html (firstname_eror + "<div class='clear'><br></div>");
                  $('#firstname_eror').show ();
                  return false;
                }
                if (lastname_eror != "") {
                  $('#lastname_eror').html (lastname_eror + "<div class='clear'><br></div>");
                  $('#lastname_eror').show ();
                  return false;
                }
```

```html
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask#
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (firstname.length < 3) firstname_eror = "Имя не меньше 3 символов";
if (lastname.length < 3) lastname_eror = "Имя не меньше 3 символов";
if (email_address.split ('@').length - 1 == 0 || email_address.split ('.').length - 1 == 0) fail = "Вы ввели некорректный адрес эл. почты";

if (firstname_eror != "") {
$('#firstname_eror').html (firstname_eror + "<div class='clear'><br></div>");
$('#firstname_eror').show ();

}
if (lastname_eror != "") {
$('#lastname_eror').html (lastname_eror + "<div class='clear'><br></div>");
$('#lastname_eror').show ();

}
```